# Minimax for Tic Tac Toe in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to implement Minimax algorithm for a tic tac toe game, the code works but minimax does not work correctly, since it doesn't pick the right moves and lets you win. If anyone could suggest why it does not work, or any general comments about the code, I would greatly appreciate it and try to learn from my mistakes.

There's my Class Board code:

```
#Import
import os
import time
import random
import copy



class Board:

    def __init__(self, cell_list):
        self.cells = cell_list



def get_possible_moves(self):

    return [i for i, j in enumerate(self.cells) if j == " "]       

def is_board_full(self):
    if " " in self.cells:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def is_winner(self, player):
    if (self.cells[1] == player and self.cells[2] == player and self.cells[3] == player) or \
        (self.cells[4] == player and self.cells[5] == player and self.cells[6] == player) or \
        (self.cells[7] == player and self.cells[8] == player and self.cells[9] == player) or \
        (self.cells[1] == player and self.cells[4] == player and self.cells[7] == player) or \
        (self.cells[2] == player and self.cells[5] == player and self.cells[8] == player) or \
        (self.cells[3] == player and self.cells[6] == player and self.cells[9] == player) or \
        (self.cells[1] == player and self.cells[5] == player and self.cells[9] == player) or \
        (self.cells[3] == player and self.cells[5] == player and self.cells[7] == player):
        return True

    else:
        return False

def print_board(self):
    print "   |   |   "
    print " "+self.cells[1]+" | "+self.cells[2]+" | "+self.cells[3]+" "
    print "   |   |   "
    print "___|___|___"
    print "   |   |   "
    print " "+self.cells[4]+" | "+self.cells[5]+" | "+self.cells[6]+" "
    print "   |   |   "
    print "___|___|___"
    print "   |   |   "
    print " "+self.cells[7]+" | "+self.cells[8]+" | "+self.cells[9]+" "
    print "   |   |   "
    print "___|___|___"


def utility(self):
    if self.is_winner("X") == True:
        return -1
    elif self.is_winner("O") == True:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def whose_turn(self): 
    pos_moves = self.get_possible_moves()
    if len(pos_moves)%2 == 1: #ODD
        return "X"
    else:
        return "O"



def is_cell_empty(self,index):
    if self.cells[index] == " ":
        return True
    else:
        return False



def make_move(self, player, index):
    self.cells[index] = player



def resulting_board(self,player,move):
    copy_of_cell = copy.deepcopy(self.cells)
    new_Board = Board(copy_of_cell)
    new_Board.make_move(player, move)
    return new_Board


def minimax(board):
    if board.is_board_full() == True:
        return board.utility()
    elif board.whose_turn() == "O":

        score = max([minimax(board.resulting_board("O",move))  for move in board.get_possible_moves()  ]  )    
        return score
    else:
        score = min ([minimax(board.resulting_board("X",move))  for move in board.get_possible_moves()  ]    )
        return score



empty_board = ["", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
Main_Board = Board(empty_board)

def get_computer_move(board):
    score = minimax(board)
    best_move = None
    pos_moves = board.get_possible_moves()
    for move in pos_moves:
        if minimax(board.resulting_board("O",move)) == score:
            best_move = move
            break
    return best_move
```

And there is my code to run the whole thing:

```
while True:
os.system("clear")
Main_Board.print_board()

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Pick an empty space, you are player X:  ")
        choice = int(choice)
        if Main_Board.is_cell_empty(choice) == True:
            Main_Board.make_move("X",choice)
            os.system("clear")
            Main_Board.print_board()
            break
        else:
            print ("Sorry, its not empty, try again")
            time.sleep(2)

    if Main_Board.is_winner("X") == True:
        print "Congrats you won!"
        break
    elif Main_Board.is_board_full() == True:
        print "Tie"
        break


    print "AI Move.."
    time.sleep(1)
    AI_move = get_computer_move(Main_Board)
    Main_Board.make_move("O",AI_move)
    os.system("clear")
    Main_Board.print_board()

    if Main_Board.is_winner("O") == True:
        print "You lost"
        break
```

Thank you

Comment: You're only checking for a winner once the board is completely full. Tic Tac Toe doesn't work that way.

Comment: Omg! Thank you! It works like a charm now.